# Match 2 columns from the same table to the same single column in another table (total of 3 joins)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables.

```
sheets TABLE
sheet_id
brand_id
sheet_color
sheet_code
adhesive_id_1
adhesive_id_2
adhesive_id_3
factor_1
factor_2
factor_3
```

```
sheet_brands TABLE
brand_id
brand_name
surface_type_id
```

```
adhesives TABLE
adhesive_id
match_code
match_name
```

I need to match:

1) sheets.brand_id to sheet_brands.brand_id to get the brand_name

2) sheets.adhesive_id_1 to adhesives.adhesive_id to get the match_code and match_name

3) sheets.adhesive_id_2 to adhesives.adhesive_id to get the match_code and match_name

I have spent awhile searching and have not found a solution that works. I believe this type of JOIN is unique because I need to match 2 columns from the same table to the same single column in another table.

This is the closest I came to solving the problem BUT it only matches the first adhesive_id_1. It does not match adhesive_id_2 or adhesive_id_3.

```
$sql = "SELECT sheet_color, sheet_code, factor_1, factor_2, brand_name, match_code, match_name FROM sheets LEFT JOIN sheet_brands ON sheet_brands.brand_id = sheets.brand_id LEFT JOIN adhesives ON adhesives.adhesive_id = sheets.adhesive_id_1";
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you chose to accept the latest answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one join on `adhesives` per column in the source table, like so:

```
SELECT 
    s.sheet_color, 
    s.sheet_code, 
    s.factor_1, 
    s.factor_2, 
    sb.brand_name, 
    a1.match_code match_code_1, 
    a1.match_name match_name_1,
    a2.match_code match_code_2, 
    a2.match_name match_name_2,
    a3.match_code match_code_3, 
    a3.match_name match_name_3  
FROM sheets s
LEFT JOIN sheet_brands sb ON sb.brand_id = s.brand_id 
LEFT JOIN adhesives a1 ON a1.adhesive_id = s.adhesive_id_1
LEFT JOIN adhesives a2 ON a2.adhesive_id = s.adhesive_id_2
LEFT JOIN adhesives a3 ON a3.adhesive_id = s.adhesive_id_3
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked when performed in phpMyAdmin but how would I access a1.match_code, a2.match_code, etc. when I go through my rows in PHP. I tried $row['a1.match_code'], $row['match_code'], etc. No results. Works fine for $row['brand_name'], $row['sheet_color'], etc.

Comment: @user1822824: you need to alias the columns - just added that to the query. Then you can access them with `$row['match_code_1']`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You must join the table `adhesives` twice to get both `match_code`s and `match_name`s:

```
SELECT s.sheet_color, s.sheet_code, s.factor_1, s.factor_2, 
       b.brand_name, 
       a1.match_code match_code1, a1.match_name match_name1,
       a2.match_code match_code2, a2.match_name match_name2
FROM sheets s
LEFT JOIN sheet_brands b ON b.brand_id = s.brand_id 
LEFT JOIN adhesives a1 ON a1.adhesive_id = s.adhesive_id_1
LEFT JOIN adhesives a2 ON a2.adhesive_id = s.adhesive_id_2
```

Use aliases for the tables and qualify the column names with these aliases.
If you want also the `match_code` and `match_name` for `adhesive_id_3` you will need one more join:

```
SELECT s.sheet_color, s.sheet_code, s.factor_1, s.factor_2, 
       b.brand_name, 
       a1.match_code match_code1, a1.match_name match_name1,
       a2.match_code match_code2, a2.match_name match_name2,
       a3.match_code match_code3, a3.match_name match_name3
FROM sheets s
LEFT JOIN sheet_brands b ON b.brand_id = s.brand_id 
LEFT JOIN adhesives a1 ON a1.adhesive_id = s.adhesive_id_1
LEFT JOIN adhesives a2 ON a2.adhesive_id = s.adhesive_id_2
LEFT JOIN adhesives a3 ON a3.adhesive_id = s.adhesive_id_3
```